# Show one value for an item on the page, but post a different value

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with a large number of items, generated using a tabular form. It is a table of budget entries. Each budget entry might be a single annual budget amount, or it might be a set of twelve monthly budget amounts.

I've implemented this with an "Amount Type" select list which is either 'YEAR' or 'MONTH', followed by 13 items - an Annual Amount followed by 12 amounts for each month of the year.

- If Amount Type is YEAR, or the user changes it to YEAR, the Annual Amount item is enabled and the monthly amounts are disabled.
- If Amount Type is MONTH, or the user changes it to MONTH, the Annual Amount item is disabled (while still showing the value that had been entered).

The value "behind" a disabled item is still important, however; it must be posted when the page is submitted; this is so that if the user changes from, say, MONTH back to YEAR, their original annual budget is restored.

[image: sample screenshot]

**Now, all the above works great. What I'd like to add is:**

- If Amount Type is MONTH, I'd like to dynamically show the total of the month items *within* (or perhaps on top of) the (disabled) annual amount item; also,
- If Amount Type is YEAR, I'd like to dynamically take the annual amount entered, divide by 12, and show the result in each of the (disabled) monthly items.

However, I don't want to change the underlying value for each of the disabled items; when the page is posted, the original values of the disabled items should be retained, not the calculated versions.

For example, say a user has a budget entry with Amount Type = YEAR, with an annual amount entered (and saved to the database) of $120,000. All the monthly amounts will initially be NULL on the database.

Now, the user changes Amount Type = MONTH, which causes the Annual Amount item to become disabled. They enter some amounts, e.g. $1000 for July, and $2000 for August. When they save the changes, the database will have stored (MONTH, 100000, 1000, 2000, null, ... null) - in other words, I've kept the old annual amount (in case the user flips back to an annual budget). But for display purposes, I'd like the annual amount item to show $3000.

My problem is, if I add some javascript to populate the annual amount item with the sum of all the monthly figures, I'll overwrite the $100,000 and if the user flips back to YEAR, it won't "restore" their original annual budget amount.

The user is allowed to flip back and forth between YEAR and MONTH, and enter values for both types; all the values the user enters must be saved to the database.

So I'd like to show one value on screen, while keeping the original value in the underlying item for when the page is posted.

Please note that my skills with javascript are limited - what I've done so far is based on a lot of googling.

*tl;dr*

I'd like an input item that, when readOnly, shows one value on the page, but posts a different value when the page is submitted.

*Oracle Apex 4.1*

*Note: the solution must work with IE7, which is the SOE here.*

Comment: is this a manual tabular form, or a wizard generated one?

Comment: Also: let's say the user enters a year amount and no months amounts. Save. Year amount is displayed and the monthly values (year/12) are shown instead of null. Now the user flips the type to month instead of year, disabling year and enabling month. August's value is changed. Save. Q: is only august to be saved now? Continued: the change of august changes the total also, and let's say no save was done. User flips type from month to year. Save. Q: which value? Q:If user does change year amount, what happens to august's value?

Comment: If amount type is YEAR, all the monthly amounts are saved, but ignored in the calculations - as far as the user is concerned, those month figures don't exist. If the user flips to MONTH, the annual amount is saved internally, but is not visible and is ignored in calculations - and the previously saved monthly figures are "restored" on screen so the user can see them, and are now used in calculations. If they flip back and forth, I always save the last entered amount for ALL items.

Comment: As it is, however, I've solved this by adding a display field that will show either the Annual Total (if amount type is YEAR) or the sum of the Month amounts (if amount type is MONTH) and I'm not going to bother showing the Annual/12 in the month fields, I'd have to create another 12 fields and write the javascript to maintain them all; and I suspect the users won't mind that so much.

Comment: We just had a meeting with some of the key users an hour ago and it's apparent to me now that for many budgets, dividing the annual total by 12 is a simplistic and sometimes misleading view of reality anyway. I'll just show the total of the monthly amounts if it's a monthly budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to NoPyGod whose comments have led me to a working solution.

I've added an extra field into my tabular form, TOTAL_AMOUNT_DSP, and hidden the underlying database field TOTAL_AMOUNT. I use javascript to set TOTAL_AMOUNT_DSP and make it editable or readonly depending on amount type.

To get around the "Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process." error, I've replaced the default MRU process with a custom update procedure:

```
FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01.COUNT LOOP
  UPDATE budget_entries
  SET amount_type  = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f02(i)
     ,total_amount = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f03(i)
     ,month1       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f05(i)
     ,month2       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f06(i)
     ,month3       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f07(i)
     ,month4       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f08(i)
     ,month5       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f09(i)
     ,month6       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f10(i)
     ,month7       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f11(i)
     ,month8       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f12(i)
     ,month9       = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f13(i)
     ,month10      = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f14(i)
     ,month11      = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f15(i)
     ,month12      = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f16(i)
  WHERE budget_entry_id = APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01(i); 
END LOOP;
```

The only downside to this approach is that I don't get the builtin Apex protection if more than one user updates the rows around the same time; basically "last update wins". I've remedied this with a simple lost update detection based on a version column on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden fields to store the real values

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Update the hidden fields when the real fields change

Then you can display whatever you want in the visual-only fields (don't give them a name and they won't be included in the form post data)

Comment: Not sure - I was thinking along slightly different lines originally, i.e. generating hidden items to hold the calculated values, and dynamically showing the hidden calculated items on top of the disabled items. Your idea of having hidden fields to store the actual values for posting to the database might work - I'm not sure if it will work with Apex's tabular form which I've found is easy to muck up badly. I'll have a play and see.

Comment: Main issue at the moment is when I have the hidden item, I get the dreaded *"Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process."* when submitting the page.

Comment: Remove any extra fields you have added and set the original fields to type=hidden and try submitting again, are you still getting that error? Is the error client (javascript) or server side?

Comment: The error is from Apex, i.e. server side. If I remove the derived field the error goes away. I think what I need is a text item that is editable but not posted to the db.

Comment: Yes, and you can achieve this by removing the name attribute from the input.

Comment: If I add an extra editable item using APEX_ITEM.text(), it shows the item but it doesn't give it an id, so I can't reference the item for each row individually in my javascript.

Comment: You need to find a way to put your own ID on it

Comment: Can you just put <input type=text id=bla> without using the APEX_ITEM.text() helper?

Comment: Ok I'm getting close. I have used APEX_ITEM.text() to generate the display-only item, and given it an ID ("f16_0001") which works for the first record on the screen. I can submit without error. Now I just need to work out how to generate the row number for each row correctly, e.g. "f16_0001", "f16_0002", etc.

Comment: Well that didn't work. I'm going to try removing the name attribute from the Apex-generated item instead, and see if that stops the item being posted.

Comment: Can you not just inject your own HTML? Do you have to use the APEX_ITEM helpers? Is there no APEX_ITEM.hidden() ?

Comment: I tried removing the name attribute, but now the server raises No Data Found (probably because it's trying to get the value of the items from which I removed the name attribute).

Comment: Your hidden input needs a name attribute

Comment: If I have to do it all in HTML I think I'd rather just go back to the client and say, "can't be done" because of the sheer amount of functionality that I get from Apex for free.

Comment: but "Yes, and you can achieve this by removing the name attribute from the input."

Comment: Yes. Remove name attibutes from your visible/editable inputs, but DO USE name attributes on your hidden inputs. I'm really not to sure about Apex, but I assume you are creating an HTML template?

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not creating a HTML template, I'm just using the ones provided. I was removing the name from the visible/editable input, but the Apex engine was expecting them to be posted.

Comment: Ok, I've come up with a working solution, thanks heaps NoPyGod, your comments really helped.